# Create a new array from a unknown depth multidimensional and keep the same structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that can have any depth. What im trying to do is to filter the whole path based on ***dynamic keys*** and create a new array of it.

Example of the array

```
$originalArray = [
    "title" => "BACKPACK MULTICOLOUR",
    "description" => "description here",
    "images" => [
        [
            "id" => 12323123123,
            "width" => 635,
            "height" => 560,
            "src" => "https://example.com",
            "variant_ids": [32694976315473, 32863017926737],
        ],
        [
            "id" => 4365656656565,
            "width" => 635,
            "height" => 560,
            "src" => "https://example.com",
            "variant_ids": [32694976315473, 32863017926737],
        ]
    ],
    "price" => [
        "normal" => 11.00,
        "discount" => [
            "gold_members" => 9.00,
            "silver_members" => 10.00,
            "bronze_members" => null
        ]
    ]
];
```

Example how the output should look like with the key "title, width, height, gold_members" filtered out. Only keys from the end of the array tree should be valid, so nothing must happen when ***images*** is in the filter

```
$newArray = [
    "title" => "BACKPACK MULTICOLOUR",
    "images" => [
        [
            "width" => 635,
            "height" => 560,
        ],
        [
            "width" => 635,
            "height" => 560,
        ]
    ],
    "price" => [
        "discount" => [
            "gold_members" => 9.00,
        ]
    ]
];
```

I guess that i should create a function that loop through each element and when it is an associative array, it should call itself again

Because the filtered paths are unknown i cannot make a hardcoded setter like this:

```
$newArray["images"][0]["width"] = 635
```

The following filter will be an example but it should basically be dynamic

example what i have now:

```
$newArray = handleArray($originalArray);
    

handleArray($array) 
{
    $filter = ["title", "width", "height", "gold_members"];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $this->handleArray($value);
        } else {
            if (in_array($key, $filter)) {
                // put this full path in the new array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Solved] Update:

I solved my problem thanks to [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot)

I used his code and added an extra check to add an array with multiple values to the new array

My code to solve the issue:

```
<?php
function isListOfValues($array) {            
    $listOfArrays = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $listOfArrays[] = ! is_array($value) && is_int($key);
    }

    return array_sum($listOfArrays) === count($listOfArrays);
}

function filterKeysRecursive(&$arr, &$keep) {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && ! isListOfValues($value)) {
            $value = filterKeysRecursive($value, $keep);
            
            if (count($value)) {
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }                    
        } else if (array_key_exists($key, $keep)) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}

$keep = array_flip(["title", "width", "height", "gold_members"]);
        
$result = filterKeysRecursive($originalArray, $keep);
```

Comment: How about using just `unset` on keys  that you want to filter out?

Comment: As "images" is not in your filter list, why does your desired result still have "images" keys?

Comment: In your example if you would have a multiple keys `title` anywhere in the structure it will be also in your new array

Comment: What should happen if a `"gold_members"` key has an associative array as value with lots of keys. Should those keys be filtered, or remain as they are? If they should be filtered, and none remain, what should happen with that `"gold_members"` key... should it remain with an empty array as value, or should it be omitted?

Comment: @trincot Thank you for pointing that out. I edited my post with ***variant_ids** in ***images**, the the keys should be remain how they are when a value has a lot of keys

Comment: OK, but those are keys that are not in your list. My question is what should happen if the sub array with many properties is linked to a key that is in your list ("images" is not in your list).

Comment: @trincot Also good point thanks, then nothing should happen only the end key of a tree should be valid

Comment: @jason_decode What if different branches (like _images_ and _price/discount_) would have the same key each in one of their elements? Shouldn't the filtering happen on the full path of keys like for example _price/discount/gold_members_ and _images/?/[width|height]_ (where ? stands for an index and [] for keys which are only to be removed if they are both appearing in the same array)?

Comment: @nice_dev Edited my post and solved my issue

Comment: @jason_decode Say, you want to filter just the `images` key, so you would wish to have it's array value as well, right? Because key value pairs has to be there. It looks like the answer you accepted doesn't give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive function, with following logic:

- base case: the value associated with a key is not an array (it is a "leaf"). In that case the new object will have that key/value only when the key is in the list of desired keys.
- recursive case: the value associated with a key is an array. Apply recursion to that value. Only add the key when the returned result is not an empty array. In that case associate the filtered value to the key in the result object.

To speed up the look up in the list of keys, it is better to flip that list into an associative array.

Here is the implementation:

```
function filter_keys_recursive(&$arr, &$keep) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = filter_keys_recursive($value, $keep);
            if (count($value)) $result[$key] = $value;
        } else if (array_key_exists($key, $keep)) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$originalArray = ["title" => "BACKPACK MULTICOLOUR","description" => "description here","images" => [["id" => 12323123123,"width" => 635,"height" => 560,"src" => "https://example.com"],["id" => 4365656656565,"width" => 635,"height" => 560,"src" => "https://example.com"]],"price" => ["normal" => 11.00,"discount" => ["gold_members" => 9.00,"silver_members" => 10.00,"bronze_members" => null]]];

$keep = array_flip(["title", "width", "height", "gold_members"]);

$result = filter_keys_recursive($originalArray, $keep);
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposition to you is to write a custom function to transform structure from one schema to another:

```php
function transform(array $originalArray): array {
    array_walk($originalArray['images'], function (&$a, $k) {
      unset($a['id']); unset($a['src']);
    });
    unset($originalArray['description']);
    unset($originalArray['price']['normal']);
    unset($originalArray['price']['discount']['silver_members']);
    unset($originalArray['price']['discount']['bronze_members']);
    
    return $originalArray;
}
var_dump(transform($originalArray));
```

If you are familiar with OOP I suggest you to look at how [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) works in API Platform for [example](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/) and inject this idea into your code by creating custom DataTransformers where you specify which kind of structers you want to support with transformer and a method where you transform one structure to another.

Comment: Im sorry, i wasn't really clear in my description that the full path keys will always be unknown to me so hardcoding the keys will not help because the array can be any size and have any keys and the ***filter**  keys are ***dynamic**. I edited my post with an example what im trying to do. My apologies

Comment: Yeah, now I understand your problem, but with array structure that is completly dynamic you will not solve your problem. Think about if `images` would have `title` field. You need to save `title` from root of an array, but in your solution you will also save `title` for `images`. You need to make some validation on that input array and make it more strict, at least the keys that are important to your transformation.

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate over the array recursively on each key and subarray.
- If the current key in the foreach is a required key in the result then:

  - If the value is not an array, simply assign the value
  - If the value is an array, iterate further down over value recursively just in case if there is any other filtering of the subarray keys that needs to be done.
- If the current key in the foreach is *NOT* a required key in the result then:

  - Iterate over value recursively if it's an array in itself. This is required because there could be one of the filter keys deep down which we would need. Get the result and only include it in the current subresult if it's result is not an empty array. Else, we can skip it safely as there are no required keys down that line.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function filterKeys($array, $filter_keys) {
    $sub_result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($key, $filter_keys)){// if $key itself is present in $filter_keys
            if(!is_array($value)) $sub_result[$key] = $value;       
            else{
                $temp = filterKeys($value, $filter_keys);
                $sub_result[$key] = count($temp) > 0 ? $temp : $value;
            }
        }else if(is_array($value)){// if $key is not present in $filter_keys - iterate over the remaining subarray for that key
            $temp = filterKeys($value, $filter_keys);
            if(count($temp) > 0) $sub_result[$key] = $temp;
        }
    }
    
    return $sub_result;
}

$result = filterKeys($originalArray, ["title", "width", "height", "gold_members"]);

print_r($result);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/4b175)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
    $expectedKeys = ['title','images','width','height','price','gold_members'];

    function removeUnexpectedKeys ($originalArray,$expectedKeys)
    {
        foreach ($originalArray as $key=>$value) {
          if(is_array($value)) {
            $originalArray[$key] = removeUnexpectedKeys($value,$expectedKeys);
            if(!is_array($originalArray[$key]) or count($originalArray[$key]) == 0) {
                unset($originalArray[$key]);
            }
          } else {
              if (!in_array($key,$expectedKeys)){
                  unset($originalArray[$key]);
              }
          }
        }
        return $originalArray;
    }
    
    $newArray = removeUnexpectedKeys ($originalArray,$expectedKeys);
    print_r($newArray);
```

check this on editor,
https://www.online-ide.com/vFN69waXMf